# What services would one add to the api/services folder in sails.js

Tags: sails.js

I have a question consisting of two parts:

1. What are the types of services one would add to the api/services folder in a sails.js app.
2. How would one 'wire' those services to the rest of the application.

Thanks,

TM

Answer (score 49, accepted):

a service would be in my opinion, a piece of logic that you need in multiple locations of your app. for example an email service. the following is taken directly from the [sails-wiki](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-wiki/blob/0.9/services.md) github page.

```
// EmailService.js - in api/services
exports.sendInviteEmail = function(options) {

var opts = {"type":"messages","call":"send","message":
    {
        "subject": "YourIn!",
        "from_email": "info@balderdash.co",
        "from_name": "AmazingStartupApp",
        "to":[
            {"email": options.email, "name": options.name}
        ],
        "text": "Dear "+options.name+",\nYou're in the Beta! Click <insert link> to verify your account"
    }
};

myEmailSendingLibrary.send(opts);
};
```

The wiring is done by sails itself:

```
// Somewhere in a conroller
 EmailService.sendInviteEmail({email: 'test@test.com', name: 'test'});
```

Comment: how would I create a service that returns some JSON?

Comment: you can't bind a service to a route. you have to return a promise or hand over a callback and handle the rendering inside your controller

Comment: What do you mean with a promise? I currently made my service accept a callback function and let the controller handle the data through there

Comment: promises are just another way of handling your async calls. https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird#what-are-promises-and-why-should-i-use-them