# How to get returned object from different action on sails.js?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, controller, sails.js, action

I'm still new to sails.js and currently trying to get returned object from different action.

What currently I know is if I use 'getUserTransaction' action inside 'UserController', then I can only return it to 'getUserTransaction.ejs' view using locals (_.each). (CMIIW)
example:

```
//UserController
getUserTransaction: function (req, res, next){
   UserTransaction.find({user:req.param('userid')}).exec(function foundTransactions(err, transactions){
      if(err) return next(err);

      if(!transactions) return next();

      res.view({
         transactions: transactions
      });
   });
}

//getUserTransaction.ejs 
...
<% _.each(transactions, function(transaction){ %>
   <tr>
       <td><%= transaction.data %></td>
       <td><a href="<%= transaction.path %>">Link</a></td>
   </tr>
<% }); %>
...
```

But, what if I want to return object from 'getUserHobby' action indside 'UserController' to 'getUserTransaction.ejs' view?.
this is my code and I can't get it right

```
//UserController
getUserHobby: function (req, res, next){
   UserHobby.find({user:req.param('userid')}).exec(function foundHobbies(err, hobbies){
      if(err) return next(err);

      if(!hobbies) return next();

      res.view('user/getUserTransaction', {
         hobbies: hobbies
      });
   });
}

//getUserTransaction.ejs
...
<% _.each(hobbies, function(hobby){ %>
   <tr>
       <td><%= hobby.type %></td>
       <td><%= hobby.name %></td>
   </tr>
<% }); %>
...
```

And I've tried to do it and returned 'hobbies undefined'. So how I should get it right.

Regards

Comment: Is your `getUserTransaction.ejs` file located in the `views/user/` folder?

Comment: yes, `getUserTransaction.ejs` is located in the `views/user/` folder

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question. Please clarify it (is the first part about what you know useless? "And I've tried to do it and returned 'hobbies undefined'"?)

Comment: It is not useless. The first time I try it, hobbies return undefined. After I tried your solution, it solved the 'undefined' problem but still list of hobbies is not shown to `getUserTransactions.ejs`. The list of hobbies is shown only to `getUserHobby.ejs` because the views file name is the same with the action named `getUserHobby` in UserController. What I asked is how to get data from action that named `getUserHobby` to `getUserTransaction.ejs` ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand what you want to achieve. Do you want to display the `transactions` and `hobbies` lists in the same view?

Comment: Yes.. I want to display list of transactions and hobbies in the same view through different action. Sorry for bad description.

Comment: I think I've understood now, I've edited my answer below

Comment: Hi @Yann Bertrand. Actually, I already know those answer since the beginning. But, what I want to ask is it possible to display list of transactions and hobbies using different(separated) actions? Get data from `getUserTransactions` action and from `getUserHobby` action, and then send it to `getUserTransactions.ejs` view. Because I want to do real-time table pagination to Transactions and Hobbies within the same view. Because we need callbacks to the actions  for `.paginate()` right? If there is no other answer, what you said is the correct answer. What do you think? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85274/discussion-between-yann-bertrand-and-john-elmer-jo-el).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of, in a [Sails controller](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/controllers) action, you shouldn't use the 3rd param (`next`).

> Unlike Express middleware methods, Sails controller actions should always be the last stop in the request chain--that is, they should always result in either a response or an error. While it is possible to use `next` in an action method, you are strongly encouraged to use policies instead wherever possible.

You should use the built in [response](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/response-res) methods **even if you want to throw an error**.

Here is how I would write my controller action:

```
// Inside api/controllers/UserController.js
getUserTransactions: function (req, res) {
  if(!req.param('userid'))
    return res.badRequest(); // Send a 400 response back down to the client indicating that the request is invalid

  UserTransaction
    .find({ user: req.param('userid') })
    .exec(function foundTransactions(err, transactions){
      if(err)
        return res.negotiate(err); // Send an appropriate error response back down to the client

      // If there is no transactions, you can display a message in your view
      return res.ok({ transactions: transactions }); // Send a 200 ("OK") response back down to the client with the provided data
  });
}
```

And here is how you could write your corresponding view:

```
// Inside views/user/getUserTransaction.ejs
<% if(data.transactions.length) { %>
    <!-- display each transactions... -->
    ...
<% } else { %>
    <p>This user has no transaction yet.</p>
<% } %>
```

---

For your other action, here is how you can use [`res.ok`](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/response-res/res-ok) with a `pathToView` param

```
res.ok({ hobbies: hobbies }, 'user/getUserTransactions');
```

Your view has to be located in the `views/user/getUserTransactions.ejs` file in order to run correctly.

---

Now we've reviewed your code, we can answer your question.

So you want to call an controller's action in another one. This is [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20994036/3215167) but not recommended.

Here is what you should do:

```
// api/controllers/UserController.js
// In your getUserTransactions method (you should change its name)
// Get the user transactions
UserTransaction
  .find({ user: req.param('userid') })
  .exec(function foundTransactions(err, transactions) {
    if(err) return res.negotiate(err);

    // Get the user hobbies
    UserHobby
      .find({ user: req.param('userid') })
      .exec(function foundHobbies(err, hobbies) {
        if(err) return res.negotiate(err);

        return res.ok({
          transactions: transactions,
          hobbies: hobbies
        });
   });
});
```

You can also use [services](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/anatomy/my-app/api/services) to simplify your controllers.

```
// api/services/UserService.js
module.exports.getUserTransactions = function (userId, cb) {
  UserTransaction
    .find({ user: userId })
    .exec(cb);
};

module.exports.getUserHobbies = function (userId, cb) {
  UserHobby
    .find({ user: userId })
    .exec(cb);
};

// Inside api/controllers/UserController.js
UserService
  .getUserTransactions(req.param('userid'), function (err, transactions) {
    if(err) return res.negotiate(err);

    UserService
      .getUserHobbies(req.param('userid'), function (err, hobbies) {
        if(err) return res.negotiate(err);

        return res.ok({
          transactions: transactions,
          hobbies: hobbies
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and correction. I'm still new to sails.js, so I'm gonna try on it.

Comment: Hi @Yann Bertrand, I tried  to do it like you. But there is a problem if I use `res.ok`. It become transactions is undefined, even I already put `res.ok({transactions: transactions}, 'user/getUserTransaction')` and already use the routing point.

But if I use `res.view`. It just returned normally. Even without routing point.

Regards

Comment: I think you have to use `data.transactions` instead of `transactions` in your views. I'll edit my answer if it works.

Comment: Hi @Yann Bertrand, after I use `data.transactions` in my views, the data returned to views. But only if action name is the same with the views filename. In this case `getUserTransactions` as action name and `getUserTransactions.ejs` as views filename. But if views filename is different, in this case `getUserHobby.ejs` can't get the returned data. Regards

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "can't get the returned data". Do you have something in that `data`? Please log `err` and `hobbies` in your controller's action.

Comment: Sorry, I think I use wrong words on comment before. What I mean is, the data that returned from `getUserHobby` through `data.hobbies` is not empty in `getUserHobby.ejs`. But, returned empty in `getUserTransactions.ejs`

Comment: So `data.transactions` is `undefined` in `getUserTransactions.ejs`?

Comment: No, `data.transactions` and `data.hobbies` is already defined. The problem is, I want to put `data.hobbies` in `getUserTransactions.ejs` but returned empty data. If I put `data.hobbies` in `getUserHobby.ejs` returned data.